# Reversing washing machine motor

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor, appliances

I know how to reverse a single phase induction motor. 
I also try to understand it using this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150158/washing-machine-motor). But, I can't understand how to reverse the motor of fallowing wiring diagram. In this diagram, RED and BLUE terminals connected to TRIAC separately.

[image: wiring diagram]

How this motor start,stop,and change direction according to this diagram?
How about internal connection to the winding of this motor?

Comment: Is this has something like this internal connection as this question?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244055/asynchronous-motor-with-motor-capacitor-sometimes-wont-run-backwards-when-it-sh

Comment: Old fashion washing machine motors are specially made to reverse directions for washing then spinning the load.  I don't know if this applies in this case, but I found this on the net: "In a single phase induction motor, the direction is controlled by a starting capacitor. Change the pole on which it it placed will reverse the direction it starts and then runs in."  I found it [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-reverse-the-rotation-of-a-AC-motor).

Comment: "How this motor start, stop and change direction according to this diagram?" - That's what *Electronic Controller* block is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very likely that you have something like the connection of the question linked in your comment. You likely connect power to blue and yellow for one direction and red and yellow for the opposite direction.

You probably can not determine for sure what you have without testing. Connect the motor through a switch that you can turn off quickly if there is a problem. It would be good to check the current with an ammeter before running the motor for more than a few seconds.